# Java: Dynamic type casting using enums

Tags: java, enums, casting

I am trying to do something along the lines of:

```
public void setContents(Object[] values)
{
    ...

        //A. this works
        mRank =
            ((String)(values[Columns.RANK.index])); 

        //B. doesn't work (entire line underlined by netbeans)
        mRank =
            (Columns.RANK.type.cast(values[Columns.RANK.index]));
        //incompatible types: required java,lang.String found: java.lang.Object

        //C. doesn't work (first RANK is underlined by netbeans)
        mRank =
            ((Columns.RANK.type)(values[Columns.RANK.index]));
        //cannot find symbol symbol: class RANK location: blah.blah.Columns

    ...
}
```

Where columns is an inner enum, like so:

```
public static enum Columns
{

    RANK(0, "Rank", String.class),
    NUMBER(1, "Number", Integer.class);

    public String text;
    public Class type;
    public int index;

    private Columns(int idx, String text, Class clasz)
    {
        this.type = clasz;
        this.text = text;
        this.index = idx;
    }
}
```

I understand why line `B` doesn't work, but what I don't get is why `C` doesn't work. If I use `Columns.RANK.type` anywhere else other than in a type cast, it works fine, but one I attempt to do a typecast with the class, it compiles saying it cannot find `RANK` in the enum, which shouldn't be the case.

How to work around?

Thanks!

Comment: `javac` in JDK7 will give a rawtypes lint warning on your raw `Class` type, which should make this sort of problem more obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C` doesn't work, because `Columns.RANK.type` is not accessible at compile time.

However, `B` can be implemented using a custom generic-based class instead of `enum`:

```
class Columns<T>
{
    public static final Columns<String> RANK = new Columns<String>(0, "Rank", String.class);
    public static final Columns<Integer> NUMBER = new Columns<Integer>(1, "Number", Integer.class);

    public final Class<T> type;
    public final String text; 
    public final int index; 

    private Columns(int idx, String text, Class<T> clasz) 
    { 
        this.type = clasz; 
        this.text = text; 
        this.index = idx; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: @axtavt, excellent workaround! I'm still waiting on another another to see if it is indeed possible to accomplish this using an `enum`, else the tick goes to you.

Comment: @axtavt, just FYI, the class `Columns<T>` needed to be declared as `public static class Column<T>`, in order for it to work as suggested - inner classes cannot have static members unless they themselves are static.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that there's no good way to do this with an enum.  axtavt's answer is probably your best bet.  trashgod is basically right about why `C` doesn't work, but perhaps it could use a bit more explanation.

You need to think about how the compiler is interpreting `C`.  What's important here is the distinction between `String` and `String.class`.  You've got a casting expression like `(String)foo`.  In such an expression, the type that you're casting to (in that example, `String`) has to be the name of a type.  You wouldn't write `(String.class)foo`, because there is no class called `String.class`.  (Instead, `String.class` is just an object, an instance of `java.lang.Class` that reflects the type `String`.)

So, when the compiler sees `(Columns.RANK.type)(values[Columns.RANK.index])`, it says "ah, this is a casting expression.  So, the bit in parens at the beginning must be the *name* of the type that bguiz wants to cast to."  Then it dutifully goes off and looks for a type named `Columns.RANK.type`.  Since it's the name of a type, it's expecting it to be of the form `my.package.containing.a.Type.AndMaybe.SomeInnerTypes`.  Thus, it splits it up around the `.`s, finds the type `Columns`, and then goes off and looks for an inner type called `RANK` in `Columns`.  There is no such inner type (the constant `RANK` doesn't count), so it fails with the error you quoted.

(If it found that, it would continue looking for another inner type called `type`, and again, the field in the enum wouldn't count.)

Remember that the compiler is just following a bunch of dumb rules.  It doesn't care that you also have a constant `RANK` in your `Columns` enum.  It also doesn't know that type names are usually upper-case.  As a result its error messages are sometimes hard to interpret for a human who is carrying around all that context in his head.  :)

Comment: +1 : Very nice explanation of why compiler is spitting out the error that it is.